# grails g;datepicker how to handle partial dates

Tags: grails, gsp

I have the following datepicker in a form

```
<g:datePicker name="born" default="none" precision="day"  
noSelection="['':' ']" relativeYears="[-25..2]" 
value="${animalInstance?.born}"  />
```

Since I allow a no selection in the datepicker it's possible to enter a date with no days, no months but a valid year. It's exactly the intended behavior.

But the params come in the following format
born=""
born_year="1995"

Controller and Command object do not bind this correctly and the whole date is considered null.

Is there a proper way to handle this without doing some If...Then...Else code?